# How do you know if an equation of spring motion is overdamped?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Looking at an equation, how can you know if if it overdamped, critically damped, or under-damped?

For example:

> How can you tell that the equation $c_1e^{2x} + c_2e^{-2x}$ is overdamped?
>
> How can you tell that the equation $e^{-x}(c_1+c_2x)$ is critically damped?
>
> How can you tell that the equation $e^{-t}(c_1\cos(3t) +c_2\sin(3t))$ is underdamped?

Comment: These are not "equations", let alone ODEs, but function terms. You can find out about their behavior by looking at their graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape of these is the key.  An overdamped system will be pure exponentials (though they are usually all decreasing).  Critically damped has a term in $xe^x$.  And underdamped have oscillatory solutions, like yours with cosine and sine waves.

Comment: Can you explain why? i.e. What does having a term in $xe^x$ have to do with returning to equilibrium quickly, etc?

Comment: @Imray:  it means you have a double root in the characteristic equation, which puts it on the boundary between two real roots (overdamped) and two complex roots (underdamped)

Comment: Can you give me a real world example of overdamped and critically damped? I understand that under-damped is the motion of an ordinary spring system or pendulum that dies down over time, but I can't picture the other two.

Comment: @Imray:  they are still springs or pendulums (pendula?) but with so much friction they don't overshoot.  that is why critically damped approaches equilibrium fastest.  Overdamped is like moving through molasses-you just can't get there very fast, so reducing the damping is a good thing.  Underdamped gets you to equilibrium faster, but then you overshoot.

Comment: Just did a lot of studying on the topic yesterday, I understand it now. Thank you Ross

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Just look at how your equations are set up.

- $e^{-x}(c_1+c_2x)$ means you have repeated roots.
- $c_1e^{2x} + c_2e^{-2x}$ means you have distinct roots.
- $e^{-t}(c_1cos(3t) +c_2sin(3t))$ means you have complex conjugates roots.

The roots will tell you whether it is critically damped, overdamped, or underdamped.

Comment: But my question was deeper. Why do repeated roots mean it's critically damped? Why do distinct roots mean its overdamped?

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda2.html take a look at that site.